# Getting no such element exception when I am trying to find an element

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to identify first name field using selenium webdriver using the below but getting no element exception:

Element trying :

```
"<input onkeyup="$('#lastname').val(this.value);" type="text" class="is_required validate form-control" data-validate="isName" id="customer_lastname" name="customer_lastname" value="">"
```

xpath used:
//input[@name='customer_lastname']

Getting the below error:
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@name='customer_lastname']"}
(Session info: chrome=89.0.4389.128)
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:26:55.152Z'
System info: host: 'HEMANTH-PC', ip: '192.168.2.5', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 89.0.4389.128, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 89.0.4389.23 (61b08ee2c5002..., userDataDir: C:\Users\Hemanth\AppData\Lo...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:56336}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: ecc4ae51b43447b6f4f10573bb13424d
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//input[@name='customer_lastname']}
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:545)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:319)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:421)
at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:361)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:311)
at com.pages.LandingPage.enterlastName(LandingPage.java:36)
at stepdefinitions.Stepdefinitions.user_enters_and_click_on_create_account_button(Stepdefinitions.java:73)
at ✽.user enters "hemanth123@gmail.com" and click on create account button(file:///E:/APITESTINGWorkspace/AutomationPractice/src/test/java/com/features/RegistrationandShopping.feature:6)

Comment: Javascript is not java...

Answer (score 0):

1)Go to your browser -> Open the application manually

2)Open inspector window(i.e press function key f12 from your keyboard)

3)Go to console tab, type as below and click on enter:

```
$x("//input[@name='customer_lastname']");
```

4)If the element is identified and count is 1 in console, but in Selenium you get NoSuchElementException, then there are high chances the element you are trying to locate is inside the Iframe. If so, figure out the Iframe and switch to it, then try to call findElement method, it should work.

Comment: After restarting my machine issue is resolved.